# Python sort list by 2 parts of the string

Tags: python, list, sorting

so I started learning Python and as part of my first project I need to sort a list of strings. Each string looks like this:

```
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_#NUMBER.file_ext
```

first  I want to sort the list by the 64-hex and then sort it by the #NUMBER.
For example, if I got a list that looks like this:

```
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_2.exe
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_1.exe
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_0.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_0.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_1.exe
```

Sorting it will give me the following list:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_0.exe
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_1.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_0.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_1.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_2.exe
```

Comment: That's great, but what's your question?

Comment: How do I sort the list by 2 arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is

```
find_suffix = re.compile('(.+)(_(\d+)\.\w+)$')
text_list.sort(key = lambda x: (find_suffix.match(x).groups()[0], int(find_suffix.match(x).groups()[2])))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following to split each entry up for the key. The important part is to ensure that the number at the end is sorted numerically rather than alphabetically:

```
def sort_by(x):
    h, d = x.split('_')
    return (h, int(d.split('.')[0]))

entries = [
    "zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_2.exe",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_1.exe",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_0.exe",
    "zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_10.exe",
    "zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_1.exe"]

for entry in sorted(entries, key=sort_by):
    print entry
```

Giving the following output:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_0.exe
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_1.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_1.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_2.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_10.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `list.sort()` method

```
>>> x = ['zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_2.exe',
 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_1.exe',
 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_0.exe',
 'zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_0.exe',
 'zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_1.exe']
>>> x.sort()
>>> x
#Output
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_0.exe
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_1.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_0.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_1.exe
zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_2.exe
```

Comment: That doesn't work because if I got a number bigger than 9 - it will first sort by the left number, then to the right. So hex64_10 will come before hex64_2 for example

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
l = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_0.exe',
     'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_1.exe',
     'zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_0.exe',
     'zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_1.exe',
     'zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_123.exe',
     'zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_2.exe']

print(sorted(l, key=lambda x:__import__('re').match('\d*', x).group()))
```

output:

```
['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_0.exe',
 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_1.exe',
 'zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_0.exe',
 'zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_1.exe',
 'zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_2.exe',
 'zxcqw84c81d96792ec917b7asd541f68d70324c4eb20018b598c1d5e84182bd_123.exe']
```